# How to use the kind of TypeScript in a Single File Component with Vue?

Tags: javascript, laravel, typescript, vue.js

I'm trying to use the TypeScript benefits in a Vue SFC,

Install the `ts-loader`, `typescript` dependencies

I added the tsconfig.json configuration

```
// tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      // this aligns with Vue's browser support
      "target": "es5",
      // this enables stricter inference for data properties on `this`
      "strict": true,
      // if using webpack 2+ or rollup, to leverage tree shaking:
      "module": "es2015",
      "moduleResolution": "node"
    }
```

}

But when trying to compile the next component it shows me error.

```
<script lang="ts">
import Vue from "vue";
import { mapState,mapGetters } from 'vuex'


export default Vue.extend({
    data() {
        return {
            number : 0
        }
    },
    methods:{
        // error void
        upCount() : void {
            this.$store.commit('increment');
        },
        downCount() : void{
            this.$store.commit('decrement');
        },
        upCountBy() : void {
            this.$store.commit('incrementBy',{count : this.number});
        }

    },
....
```

the error

> Module parse failed: Unexpected token (45:12) You may need an
>   appropriate loader to handle this file type.

I am using VueJs together with WebPack from a Laravel and Laravel Mix base installation. How do I solve this?

Comment: Which line in the example does correspond to line 45 from the error message?

Comment: @Connum yes, it is commented in the code, the return of type void or any return marks it as error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I started using Vue and TypeScript, I ran into similiar problems at first and it took me quite a while to get it to work. Try adding this to your `webpack.config.js`

```js
...
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.tsx?$/,
          use: [{
            loader: 'ts-loader',
            options: {
              appendTsSuffixTo: [ /\.vue$/ ]
            }
          }],
          exclude: /node_modules/
        },
        // make sure vue-loader comes after ts-loader
        {
          test: /\.vue$/,
          loader: 'vue-loader'
        },
...
```

Comment: Yes, I added your answer but it still shows the same error

Comment: did you restart the webpack-dev-server? Because when you make changes to the webpack config, they'e not automatically reloaded like hot module reload. It's something that happens to me quite often. ;-)

Comment: Yes, restart and the error persists. I'm using laravel mix, could this be a detail?

Comment: I'm not familiar with lavarel myself, but it shouldn't really make a difference since this is all about the assets that will be executed client-side, not any php code. It might help if you posted your webpack config file in the question as well.

Answer (score 2):

Try and flip the order of Connum's suggested answer.

```
module: {
      rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.vue$/,
                    use: 'vue-loader',
                },
                {
                    test: /\.ts$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: [{ loader: 'ts-loader', options: { appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/] } }],
                },
              ]
}
```

Worked for me. You have installed the vue-loader?

```
npm i -D ts-loader typescript vue-loader
```